# Высота блоков не выравнивалась под высоту большего блока?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Подскажите, есть пару колонок с блоками  с разным количеством ссылок внутри. Высота блоков выравнивается под высоту самого большего блока в строке. Как сделать, чтобы этого выравнивания не было(задавать фиксированную высоту не вариант, в дальнейшем количество ссылок может меняться)? Пробовала column-count, но тоже не вариант, у блоков есть кнопка ЕЩЕ, при нажатии открываются еще ссылки и происходит весь сдвиг колонок, что не нужно.
Пример на картинках [Сейчас так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O2Nf.png) [А нужно так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCYnU.png)
[Верстка][3]

```
  [3]: https://jsfiddle.net/0j9vmhqt/7/
```

Comment: Это называется Pinterest Layout. Посмотри в инете, есть различные варианты. Но скажу сразу: если высота блока не фиксированная и зависит только от контента, то сделать такую сетку без JS вряд ли выйдет нормально.

Comment: спасибо за информацию, думаю без скриптов то же ни как.

Answer (score 0):

тебе нужно css-свойство `columns: 2` на родителе, а на ребенке `break-inside: avoid;`

вот код: https://jsfiddle.net/xu4afsqk/

Comment: Спасибо! Свойство columns уже применяла и при раскрытии вложенности в одном блоке все колонки начинают сдвигаться, что не очень удобно. Думаю без js не обойтись

Comment: а у тебя c js колонки тоже будут сдвигаться. Можно как-то обсудить с дизайнером и раскрывающийся список делать абсолютом, поверх основного. 

Ну, если решишься все-таки на js, рассмотри еще https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: спасибо за информацию!